Error 404 while reading reviews of a google location
I am trying to read all the reviews of a google location using accounts.locations.reviews.list. I cannot understand where I am making mistake that the code fails. The location exists.
my code is
public static JSONArray FetchReview(String hostname, String locationName) throws Exception {
    JSONArray finalReviews = new JSONArray();
    Credential theCredentials = Authorize.getAuthorization(hostname);
    String accessToken = theCredentials.getAccessToken();
    String baseUrl = "https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/" + locationName + "/reviews";

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    String pageToken = null;

    //      reading the next pages
    do {
        String url = baseUrl;
        if (pageToken != null) {
            url += "?pageToken=" + pageToken;  // Construct URL with pageToken
        }

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .GET()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .build();
        System.out.println("request is "+request);
        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
                JSONArray reviews = responseObject.optJSONArray("reviews");
                if (reviews != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reviews.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject review =reviews.getJSONObject(i);
                        finalReviews.put(review);

                    }
                }
                pageToken = responseObject.optString("nextPageToken", null);
            } else {
                System.err.println("failed response is "+ response);
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to fetch page: " + response.statusCode());
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("An error occurred while fetching the reviews: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Error during HTTP request", e);
        }
    } while (pageToken != null);
    
 
    return finalReviews;
}

The error is

An error occurred while fetching the reviews: Failed to fetch page:
404


Have you tried hitting that endpoint with a simple, hard-coded cURL command? That may help you identify where the breakdown is happening.

@CaptainChaos, if you mean from the playground I do not have access to our clients full info. I only have the Json
